# I try CircleCI but failed

Tags: circleci

I want use CircleCI.
I try getting start.

1. I create a new repository.
   https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/getting-started/#section=getting-started
   repository name is 'hello-world', and specific branch name 'circleci-project-setup'

```
We’ll commit the config below to duri0214/hello-world on a new branch called circleci-project-setup. If you prefer, you can use an existing config.
```

[image]

2. Setting up CircleCI
   click Set Up Project. hmm... I like python.
   [image]
3. Upload config.yml on 'circleci-project-setup' branch.
   [image]
4. 

> Click Start Building and follow the prompt to add your config to a new branch and start your first pipeline. Note: You can also manually add a config.yml to your project root under a .circleci folder and push this to your VCS provider.

`Click Start Building???` this is nothing. document is old?
I try `commit and run` button.

6. failed, failed, failed
   [image]

Why can't i

---

Next try
[image]
[image]

> error computing cache key: template: cacheKey:1:7: executing
> "cacheKey" at <checksum "requirements.txt">: error calling checksum:
> open /home/circleci/project/requirements.txt: no such file or
> directory

> #!/bin/bash -eo pipefail if true; then   pip install --user -r requirements.txt else   pip install -r requirements.txt fi
>
> ERROR: Could not open requirements file: [Errno 2] No such file or
> directory: 'requirements.txt'
>
> Exited with code exit status 1 CircleCI received exit code 1

Comment: Can you please complete the question about `Why can't I` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

oh my goodness..
I use `circleci` directory instead `.circleci`.

success...[image]

Answer (score 0):

As the documentation says, you need to place the circleci configuration in the `.circlei` directory

```
Click Start Building and follow the prompt to add your config to a new branch and start your first pipeline. Note: You can also manually add a config.yml to your project root under a .circleci folder and push this to your VCS provider.
```

About `Click Start Building` , I'm guessing it's a documentation miss, likely.

Comment: thanks, DhakkanCoder  
I am appended text. `Next try`
I found two error.

I don't know where these troubleshootings are in the documentation